How to exclude directories from gci -recurse from c:\users
I'm trying to exclude 'AppData' and 'Application Data' directories from gci -recurse output but it does not work :
PS C:\Users> gci -Force -Dir -R 2>$null | ? { ( $_.Name -notLike 'AppData' ) -and ( $_.Name -notLike 'Application Data' ) } | % FullName | sls appdata | select -f 10

C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local
C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming
C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Barco
C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Historique
C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\History
C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft
C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Temp
C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Temporary Internet Files
C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Barco\ClickShare App
C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Barco\ClickShare App\cache


PS C:\Users>

I also tried testing the value of $_.FullName but it does not work either.
I expect any directories except Appdata (or Application Data) directories.

Checking for a match on the FullName will eliminate the directories. The -notmatch operator uses regex expressions.
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\' -Force -Directory -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Where-Object { $_.FullName -notmatch '\\AppData\\' -and $_.FullName -notmatch '\\Application Data\\'} |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName


Exclude the names at the top directory first, then recurse the result.  You can pipe back to get-childitem.
gci -Force -Dir C:\Users\Default | 
  ? { $_.Name -ne 'AppData' -and $_.Name -ne 'Application Data' } | 
  gci -force -dir -R

Or -exclude literally:
# also Cookies,'Local Settings','My Documents',NetHood,PrintHood,Recent,SendTo,
# 'Start Menu',Templates
gci -Force -Dir -exclude AppData,'Application Data' C:\Users\Default | 
  gci -force -dir -R

Or actually using wildcards:
gci -Force -Dir -R C:\Users | 
  ? { $_.FullName -notlike '*\AppData*' -and 
  $_.FullName -notlike '*\Application Data*' } 

Test:
gci -Force -Dir -R C:\Users |
  ? { $_.FullName -notlike '*\AppData*' -and
  $_.FullName -notlike '*\Application Data*' } |
  % fullname | select-string 'appdata|application data'


It appears that this only works if the current working directory is the $Env:USERPROFILE directory. It did not work for me from C:\Users\.

You are interested in skipping ONLY those directories in the users home directory and not possible homonym subdirectories, right?
# base-directory to check
$Path = 'C:\Users\'

# array of names you want to skip
$DirToSkip = 'AppData', 'Application Data'

# Get all directories in the users home directories EXCEPT AppData and 'Application Data'.
# -Force added to get hidden directories
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Directory -Recurse -Depth 1 -Exclude $DirToSkip -Force 2>$null |
    # THEN get every directory in each of those directories, recursively
    # -Force added to get hidden directories
    Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse -Force


-exclude only applies to the name property not the fullname property

yes, but there is a non-zero chance there might be some sub-directory named AppData or Application Data, that's why it's necessary to use two chained Get-ChildItem with -Exclude on the first, otherwise a simple Get-ChildItem -Directory -Exclude $DirToSkip -Recurse 2>$null would have been enough

Oh my bad.  I didn't notice the -depth 1.  You forgot -force.  That doesn't work actually.

No problem. I'm unsure -Force is necessary in this instance though.

appdata and application data wouldn't show without -force because they're hidden

which would be nice, except it means OTHER hidden directories wouldn't show up as well. I'll update the answer, thanks

This doesn't seem to work right in powershell 5.1.  It still recurses below the excluded directories.
